# Spark DStream.transform().foreachRDD() vs DStream.foreachRDD()

Tags: apache-spark

So I was wondering if there would be any notable difference in first applying a transform on a direct stream then calling foreachRDD rather than doing only the latter.

Comment: I think you should read @YuvalItzchakov post: http://asyncified.io/2017/02/10/why-you-might-be-misusing-sparks-streaming-api/

Comment: It depends on the transformation you do while calling `transform`. What function are you passing to `transform()`?

Comment: Let's say this function is a simple map on the rdds (or any transformation that wouldn't cause a shuffle ) will that significantly improve performances by building a DAG (since that's basically what we do by calling the transform or any transformation) ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference would be the *transformation* you do while calling `transform()`. From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#transformations-on-dstreams), `transform` takes a function: **transform(func)**. The result would differ based on the implementation of `func`.

Simplifying the DAG in Spark's terms:

**DStream.transform().foreachRDD()** is **Transformation -> Action**

**DStream.foreachRDD()** is just an **Action**